# 'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging

Tags: maven

I am having a problem with my project that is the project pom file has an error stating that packaging should not resolve to jar but to pom. I need my project to generate a target 'jar' and I don't have any child modules, however this error is generated with another error: `Child module of pom.xml does not exist` now here goes my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.itworx.bigdata</groupId>
    <artifactId>MediaSensor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>MediaSensor</name>
    <description>Complete and Integrated Spark Flow of Big Data</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <!-- please stick to the CDH version and this repositry do not use apache repos -->
    <!-- All CDH jars in this link http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html#concept_jhf_dcz_bs_unique_2-->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- following jar is implicitly needed by one of spark ref -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.6.0_24</version>
            <systemPath>C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itworx.epenta</groupId>
            <artifactId>ePenta</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <systemPath>D:/Capability_Building/Media_Sensor_Development/temp_space/ePenta.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itworx.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-writer</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <systemPath>D:/Capability_Building/Media_Sensor_Development/temp_space/spark-solr-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
            </systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>   -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>  -->
        <!--   <version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.htrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-hadoop-compat</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-hadoop2-compat</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-it</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-checkstyle</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-examples</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-prefix-tree</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-rest</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-shell</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!--   <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>  -->
        <!--   <artifactId>hbase-thrift</artifactId>  -->
        <!--  <version>1.0.0-cdh5.4.2</version>  -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <outputFile>D:/Capability_Building/Media_Sensor_Development/temp_space/MediaSensorShaded.jar
                    </outputFile>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*:*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>?</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

could anyone help?

Comment: Remove the  `<modules>` declaration at the end? And please use at least the auto format for your xml files, your fellow coders will thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @florian-schaetz pointed out in a comment, you have this at the end of your pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>?</module>
</modules>
```

If you don't plan on having child modules, you should remove it. By having it you are forcing Maven to think your pom as an aggregate pom (which it apparently is not).